# Unit testing in AngularJS with Jasmine and Chutzpah

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I am trying to write Unit test cases for existing SPA project built on angularJS. I get the "Can't find variable: module" error whenever I try to execute the code.

I installed the libraries using npm.

I used **Chutzpah** and **Jasmine** libraries for this.

### appModule.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [
        'ngMessages',
        'ui.router',
        'ui.router.title'
    ]).run(['REQ_TOKEN', function (REQ_TOKEN) {
        //...
    }]).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }]);
})();
```

### site.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    window.deferredBootstrapper.bootstrap({
        element: window.document,
        module: 'app',
        resolve: {
            REQ_TOKEN: ['$http', function ($http) {
                return $http.get('/.../', { ignoreLoadingBar: true, params: { ts: new Date().getTime() } });
            }]
        }
    });
})();
```

### appController.js:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

  angular
      .module('app')
      .controller('appController', appController);

  appController.$inject = ['apiServices', '$scope'];

  function appController(apiServices, $scope) {
    $scope.value = 5;
  }
})();
```

### apiServices.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

  angular
      .module('app')
      .factory('apiServices', apiServices);

  apiServices.$inject = ['$http', '$log', '$q'];

  function apiServices($http, $log, $q) {
    var clientServicesPath = '/api/ClientServices',
    service =
       {  .......  };

    return service;
  }
})();
```

### appControllerSpec.js

```
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-deferred-bootstrap/angular-deferred-bootstrap.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-ui-router-title/angular-ui-router-title.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.js" />

/// <reference path="../../modules/appmodule.js" />
/// <reference path="../../site.js" />
/// <reference path="../../factories/sharedfunctions.js" />

/// <reference path="../../services/apiservices.js" />
/// <reference path="../../controllers/appcontroller.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/jasmine-ajax/lib/mock-ajax.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js" />

describe('When using appController ', function () {
  //initialize Angular
  beforeEach(module('app'));   
  var ctrl, scope, apiServices;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    apiServices = $injector.get('apiServices');
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, apiServices) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var ctrl = $controller('appController', { $scope: scope, apiServices: apiServices });
  }));

  it('initial value is 5', function () {
    expect(scope.value).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

I get the following error:

> Test 'When using appController :initial value is 5' failed    Error:
>   [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: REQ_TOKENProvider <- REQ_TOKEN
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.1/$injector/unpr?p0=REQ_TOKENProvider%20%3C-%20REQ_TOKEN
>   in file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js (line 4418)
>         at getService
>   (file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4571:46)       at
>   file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4423:48         at
>   getService
>   (file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4571:46)       at
>   injectionArgs
>   (file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4595:68)       at
>   invoke (file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4617:31)
>     Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: REQ_TOKENProvider <-
>   REQ_TOKEN
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.1/$injector/unpr?p0=REQ_TOKENProvider%20%3C-%20REQ_TOKEN
>   in file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js (line 4418)
>         at getService
>   (file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4571:46)       at
>   file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4423:48         at
>   getService
>   (file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4571:46)       at
>   injectionArgs
>   (file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4595:68)       at
>   invoke (file:///C:/Users/Bhanu/......./lib/angular/angular.js:4617:31)
>   in
>   C:\Users\Bhanu.......\js\TestingJS\controllers\appControllerSpec.js
>   (line 43)
>
> 0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (chutzpah).

I have tried all the possible solutions but none worked for me. I ran the tests directly by right clicking the Test controller file and selecting the option "Run JS Tests".

I feel there are more pieces towards configuration. Please help me with this.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include angular-mocks.js.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. I did miss that. But I get a new error now. I updated the questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way you pass your controller services to you tests, and you are creating a new `var ctrl` variable withing forEach. Also, there is a single instance of the injector per application. You must get your controller and your service instance withing the same `inject(...)`

**Wrong**

```
var ctrl = $controller('appController', { $scope: scope, apiServices: apiServices });
```

**Right**

```
describe('When using appController ', function () {

  var ctrl, scope, apiServices;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    // Put it here for the sake of organization
    //initialize Angular
    module('app');

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // Get controller instance
    ctrl = $controller('appController');
    // Get service instance
    apiServices = $injector.get('apiServices');
  }));

  it('initial value is 5', function () {
    expect(scope.value).toBe(5);
  });

});
```

Comment: Don't we have to pass the services into controller

Comment: I have updated the question. Please look into it. Firstly, I was creating the same controller again and again instead of using the existing.

Comment: Remember that Jasmine DOES NOT instantiate your app. It merely runs your application and attaches itself to it. Hence for every test you can assume that all your controllers and all your services are already instantiated. You just need to get a hold of them.

Comment: To your last comment that is correct. I pointed that out in the answer. I hope that helps. Jasmine can get tricky with the setup but you'll love it

Comment: Thanks a load. That's a lot of info

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [deferredBootstrapper](https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap#user-content-bootstrap-config-and-strictdi),

> Since the constants that deferredBootstrapper adds to your
>   applications module are not available in your unit tests, it makes
>   sense to provide them in a global beforeEach():

So, **appControllerSpec.js** should be

```
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-deferred-bootstrap/angular-deferred-bootstrap.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-ui-router-title/angular-ui-router-title.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.js" />

/// <reference path="../../modules/appmodule.js" />
/// <reference path="../../site.js" />
/// <reference path="../../factories/sharedfunctions.js" />

/// <reference path="../../services/apiservices.js" />
/// <reference path="../../controllers/appcontroller.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/jasmine-ajax/lib/mock-ajax.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js" />

describe('When using appController ', function () {
  //initialize Angular
  beforeEach(module('app'));   
  var ctrl, scope, apiServices, REQ_TOKEN;

  beforeEach(function () {
      module(function ($provide) {
          $provide.constant('REQ_TOKEN', { token: '/dummyValue' });
      });
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, apiServices) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    REQ_TOKEN = $injector.get('REQ_TOKEN');
    apiServices = $injector.get('apiServices');
    var ctrl = $controller('appController', { $scope: scope});
  }));

  it('initial value is 5', function () {
    expect(scope.value).toBe(5);
  });
});
```